# Will installing Kali Linux wipe my system?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, kali-linux

I am using Windows 10 right now. I wanted to know that if I use VirtualBox to create a Virtual Machine with Kali Linux on it, will it wipe my system?

Comment: Please don't forget to accept answers if you find them helpful or ask for clarification if you need more help/Information!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## No.

VirtualBox is software for creating and using [virtual machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), which you can think of as being like an operating system (like Kali Linux, the "guest") running as a program inside another operating system (Windows 10, the "host").

The truth is a bit more complicated than that, and quite an interesting topic.